# I am having a problem with pointers in java. How do I fix a java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, pointers, matrix, sparse-matrix

This is a method that gets a element from a Sparse Matrix in java. I keep getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error. I have looked over the code and can't find the error.

```
public int getElement(int row,int col){
    int result = 0;
    MatrixEntry matrixentry = null;
    if ((row >= 0) && (row < getNumRows()) &&
        (col >= 0) && (col < getNumCols())) {
         if (col == colArray[col].getColumn() &&  row ==rowArray[row].getRow()){
        matrixentry = rowArray[row];
        while (matrixentry.getColumn() < col) {
                 matrixentry = matrixentry.getNextColumn();
        } // end while
                 if (matrixentry.getColumn() > col){
                     return 0;
                 }
                 if (matrixentry == null){
                     return 0;
                 }// 
             result = matrixentry.getData();

         }// 

    }// 
    return result;

} // end
```

Comment: Can you also post the stack trace?

Comment: Good lord, remove those "// end" and "//" comments.  They're worse than useless - needless clutter.

Comment: As Adam mentioned the stack trace would be extremely helpful along with the line numbers for this code within the context of the actual file it's in.  Once you know which line of your code is throwing the exception it's just a matter of figuring out which variable on that line is set to null.

Comment: @duffymo aww, c'mon, whatever helps him understand his own code is fine, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check `matrixentry` for `null` after you already used it in the while loop and to call `.getColumn()` and `.getNextColumn()`.

I guess your code would do better if you checked first:

```
    matrixentry = rowArray[row];

    while (null != maxtrixentry && matrixentry.getColumn() < col) {
         matrixentry = matrixentry.getNextColumn();
    }

    if (null == maxtrixentry || matrixentry.getColumn() > col){
        return 0;
    }
    result = matrixentry.getData();
```

Comment: There are cases when you have to check object for null. But not that one. You are the one who creates rowArray. How can it contains null objects?

Comment: The original code expects to see null objects after the loop: `if (matrixentry == null) { return 0; }` so it should check inside the loop too. Btw, who knows what gets returned from `.getNextColumn()` ? That's not part of the array per se.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you run [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) on your code as well.  It does an amazing job catching lots of little things, for example the null check on matrixentry after you've already accessed it.

Answer (score 0):

Are your rowAarray and colArray properly initialized?
According to your comment they are not.

Your code is hard to read and there are inconsistent checks like this

```
if (matrixentry.getColumn() > col) { 
    return 0;
}
if (matrixentry == null){ 
    return 0;
}
```

You call method on the object and only then check it for null.

If your are going to bind your life with the programming and it is not just a HomeWork I would recommend to you to treat your code presentation and expressiveness as your visit card.

Comment: private MatrixEntry[] rowArray = new MatrixEntry[0];

private MatrixEntry[] colArray = new MatrixEntry[0]; 

here is my initialized rowArray and colArray

Comment: But those are zero length arrays.   How do you plan to add elements to those?

Answer (score 0):

You need to preinitialize the array elements. That's covered by the basic [Sun Java Arrays tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). You could eventually use [`Arrays#fill()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) for that.